# Automatically Marking Delivery Receipts as Read In Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, rules

How does one mark delivery receipts as read automatically, specifically?

I have attempted to create a rule marking any email with the word "Delivered:" as read.

However it hasn't worked so far and I suspect it may be because Outlook doesn't recognize automatically generated messages as having subject lines.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I have a rule in my Outlook that does exactly this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to automatically mark the received mail with the subject of "Delivered:" field as read, right? If so, how did you create the rule? Please refer to the following steps and check if there're any differences from your rule:

1.File>Info>Manage Rules & Alerts>New rule…>Apply rule on messages I receive;

2.Under Select condition(s), choose ***with specific words in the subject***;

[image]

3.Click ***specific*** and fill in "Delivered:">Next;

4.Under Step1:Select action(s), choose ***mark it as read***>Next>Next>Finish.

Hope the above help.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.